# Java Clock Assignment

Tags: java, clock

For my assignment we are suppose to make a clock. We need variables of hours, minutes, and seconds and methods like setHours/getHours, setMinutes/getMinutes, setSeconds/getSeconds. I also need a addClock() method to make the sum of two clock objects and a tickDown() method which decrements the clock. Also I need a tick() method that increments a Clock object by one second.

Here is what I have so far...

```
public class Clock {

   private int hr; //store hours
   private int min; //store minutes
   private int sec; //store seconds

   // Default constructor

   public Clock () {
      setClock (0, 0, 0);
   }

   public Clock (int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
      setClock (hours, minutes, seconds);
   }

   public void setClock (int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
      if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
         hr = hours;
      else
         hr = 0;
      if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)
         min = minutes;
      else
         min = 0;
      if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)
         sec = seconds;
      else
         sec = 0;
   }

   public int getHours() {
      return hr;
   }

   public int getMinutes() {
      return min;
   }

   public int getSeconds() {
      return sec;
   }

   public void addClock( Clock secondClock ) {
      this.sec += secondClock.getSeconds();
      this.min += secondClock.getMinutes();
      //add overflow to minutes from seconds
      this.min +=(int)(this.sec/60);
      //update seconds 
      this.sec = this.sec % 60;
      this.hr += secondClock.getHours();
      //add overflow to minutes from seconds
      this.hr +=(int)(this.min/60);
      //update minutes
      this.min = this.min % 60;
      //adjust hours
      this.hr = this.hr % 24;
   }

   public void tick(){
      this.sec += 1;
      //add overflow to minutes from seconds
      this.min +=(int)(this.sec/60);
      //update seconds 
      this.sec = this.sec % 60;
      //add overflow to minutes from seconds
      this.hr +=(int)(this.min/60);
      //update minutes
      this.min = this.min % 60;
      //adjust hours
      this.hr = this.hr %24;
   }

   public void tickDown(){
      this.sec -= 1;
      if(this.sec <0){
         this.sec+=60;
         this.min-=1;
      }
      if(this.min<0){
         this.min+=60;
         this.hr-=1;
      }
      if(this.hr<0){
         this.hr+=24;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you re-format your code to make it readable and replace `If` with `if`. I would make sure your code compiles before writing any more.

Comment: What is your question?  Be specific.

Comment: Also, make sure you remove _semicolons_ after the if statements!

Comment: [The homework tag has been deprecated/obsoleted and should no longer be used.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag).

Comment: @Lion I didn't know that, thanks for the link. It was I that added the tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can write `addClock()` as below:

```
    public void addClock(Clock secondClock){
       this.second += secondClock.getSecond();
       this.minute+= secondClock.getMinute();
       //add overflow to minutes from seconds
       this.minute+=(int)(this.second/60);
       //update seconds 
        this.second = this.second % 60;
       this.hour += secondClock.getHour();
       //add overflow to minutes from seconds

        this.hour+=(int)(this.minute/60);
       //update minutes
        this.minute= this.minute% 60;

        //adjust hours
        this.hour = this.hour%24;
    }
```

Similarly you can write `tick` and `tickDown` methods, with only difference that **you will not have any argument in the method and you need to readjust minutes and hours after adding subtracting 1 from seconds**

```
  public void tick(){
       this.second += 1;
       //add overflow to minutes from seconds
       this.minute+=(int)(this.second/60);
       //update seconds 
       this.second = this.second % 60;
       //add overflow to minutes from seconds
        this.hour+=(int)(this.minute/60);
       //update minutes
        this.minute= this.minute% 60;
        //adjust hours
        this.hour = this.hour%24;
    }

  public void tickDown(){
       this.second -= 1;
       if(this.second <0){
          this.second+=60;
          this.minute-=1;
        }
       if(this.minute<0){
          this.minute+=60;
          this.hour-=1;
        }
       if(this.hour<0){
          this.hour+=24;
       }
    }
```

Add `main` method as :

```
   public static void main(String[]  args){
      Clock clock1 = new Clock(2,4,7);
      Clock clock2 = new Clock(8,26,57);
      clock1.tick();
      int newSeconds = clock1.getSeconds();
      //validate it should be 8 now

      clock2.tickDown();
      newSeconds = clock1.getSeconds();
      //validate it should be 56 now

      clock1.addClock(clock2);
      //get Hour, minute and second from clock1 and validate
      int newHour = clock1.getHours();
      int nuwMinute = clock1.getMinutes();
      newSeconds = clock1.getSeconds();
      //validate if they are with the right expected value or not
  }
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! I am coding this in BlueJ and it seems to have a problem with the IfElse statement towards the top of my original code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean `setClock` method? Are you trying to set values to `0`, if they are passed high i.e. if some passes minute as `75`, do you want to set that to `0`. Also, is there any specific problem, which you are referring?

Comment: I fixed it, I had the if else capitalized, but it works now. Now I am trying to add the tick(), tickDown(), and the main method that you mentioned before. Do these methods all go into the same class program?

Comment: If you are talking about `;` in `if(0 <= hours && hours < 24);{`, simply remove `;` from end of all `if`s like this `if(0 <= hours && hours < 24); {`-->change it to ` if(0 <= hours && hours < 24) {`

Comment: Yes, they all will go in same class i.e. `Class`.  `main` method is up to you. If you want to run the `Clock` class itself, then have it in `clock` method otherwise, you can have it another class e.g. `ClockTest`, where you instantiate `clock` objects as mentioned in the above main method and run it.

Comment: I have been working on this and things are going great. Everything complies in the clock class, but not the tester class. There is an error with the ".add" saying "cannot find symbol - method add(clock)" Any ideas?

Comment: Where have you defined `add(Clock clock)` method? It should be defined in `Clock` class as `public void addClock(Clock secondClock)`. If still facing issue, update the question with your latest code. I will have a look.

Comment: Alright, I updated the post with the code that I currently have. By the way, thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: Ooops.. It was a simple typing mistake. We named the method as `addClock` in `Clock` class, while we were calling it as `add` in the test case(main). Either rename the method to `add` in `Clock` class or use `addClock` in main (test code). Also I noticed, couple of `s` were missing in `main` method sample code. **I updated the answer with fixed method names**.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the tick logic by just maintaining the ticks.
Extract hour, minutes and seconds from the tick values.

```
public Clock
{
 long ticks = 0;
 public void tick()
 {
   ticks++;
 }

 public void tickDown()
 {
  ticks--;
 }

 public int getSeconds()
 {
   return ticks % 60;
 }

 public int getMinutes()
 {
   return (ticks / 60) % 60;
 }

 public int getHours()
 {
      return (ticks / (60 * 60)) % 24;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn more about the Java language. ;-)

```
if( condition ) { /* no ';' here */
   <block when true>
}
else {
   <block when false>
}
```

The main is missing, I propose

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
   Clock c1 = new Clock( 9, 59, 59 );
   c1.tickSeconds();
   System.err.println( c1 ); // You have to overload toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Clock() {
    this.hours = 12;
    this.minutes = 0;
    this.seconds = 0;
}

public Clock(int seconds) {
    this(seconds/3600, seconds%3600/60, seconds%3600%60);

}

public Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    this.hours = hours;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

public void setClock(int seconds) {
    this.seconds += seconds;
    this.minutes += minutes;
    this.minutes +=(int)(this.seconds/60);
    this.seconds = this.seconds % 60;
    this.hours += hours;
    this.hours +=(int)(this.minutes/60);
    this.minutes = this.minutes % 60;
    this.hours = this.hours % 24;
}


public int getHours() {
    return hours;
}

public void setHours(int hours) {
    this.hours = hours;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
    this.minutes = minutes;
}

public int getSeconds() {
    return seconds;
}

public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

public void tick() {
    this.seconds += 1;
    this.minutes +=(int)(this.seconds/60);
    this.seconds = this.seconds % 60;
    this.hours +=(int)(this.minutes/60);
    this.minutes = this.minutes % 60;
    this.hours = this.hours %24;
}

public void tickDown() {
    this.seconds -= 1;
    if(this.seconds <0){
        this.seconds+=60;
        this.minutes-=1;
    }
    if(this.minutes<0){
        this.minutes+=60;
        this.hours-=1;
    }
    if(this.hours<0){
        this.hours+=24;
    }
}

public void addClock(Clock clock) {
    this.seconds += clock.getSeconds();
    this.minutes += clock.getMinutes();
    this.minutes +=(int)(this.seconds/60);
    this.seconds = this.seconds % 60;
    this.hours += clock.getHours();
    this.hours +=(int)(this.minutes/60);
    this.minutes = this.minutes % 60;
    this.hours = this.hours % 24;
}

public Clock subtractClock(Clock clock) {

    if(this.seconds < clock.getSeconds()){
        --this.minutes;
        this.seconds += 60;
    }
    if(this.minutes < clock.getMinutes()){
        --this.hours;
        this.minutes += 60;
    }
    this.seconds -= clock.getSeconds();
     this.minutes -= clock.getMinutes();
     this.hours -= clock.getHours();
    return new Clock(hours,minutes,seconds);
}

public String toString() {
    String result = "(";
    String hh = "";
    String mm = "" + ":";
    String ss = "" + ")";
    if (hours < 10) {
        hh = "0" + String.valueOf(hours) + ":";
    }else {
        hh = String.valueOf(hours) +  ":";
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        mm = "0" + String.valueOf(minutes) + ":";
    }else {
        mm = String.valueOf(minutes) + ":";
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        ss = "0" + String.valueOf(seconds) +")";
    }else {
        ss = String.valueOf(seconds) +")";
    }
    result += (hh+mm+ss);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).